# What (analytical or numerical) method can I use to solve scalar optimal problem?

Tags: real-analysis, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, global-optimization

I got the following optimization problem in mind and I am looking for some (analytic or numerical) methods to solve it. Can anyone have any ideas? Here is problem

> \begin{aligned}
> & {\text{maximize}}
> & & F(x) \\
> & \text{subject to}
> & & x \geq 0, \\
> & & &x + y \leq d,\\
> & & &y = f(x)
> \end{aligned}
>   where $F(x), f(x)$ are scalar function and I assume that $f(x) \geq 0$ for all $x \geq 0$ and $d$ is a positive constant.

What I would try so far is to first generating the mesh points $0 = x_0 < x_1 < x_{n-1} < x_n = d$ for variable $x$. Then, find maximal element in the sequence $\{F(x_i), i= 0,\ldots, n: x_i + f(x_i) \leq d\}$ could be done in $O(n)$ steps. But I am looking for some alternative and more efficient methods.
Thank you in advance !

Comment: The maximum is either at $x=0$, or some $x$ where $x + f(x) = d$, or at a local maximum of $F$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Many thanks. Do you know which method can I use to find all local maximum of F(x)?

Comment: Look up [Global optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_optimization)